# SVG Coordinates not working with % values

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, clip-path

I'm using the following SVG code:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
            <polygon points="43.85 0, 77.55 0, 60.7 29.95"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.full_screen_slider_block .swiper .bg_image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
```

To try and clip a shape from a background image, but in my attempts to make it "responsive" I need to use "%" values instead of "px" values. The values below are the ones I need but as a percentage e.g.

The first value is 43.85% but instead my SVG shape is starting at 43.85px from the left side instead.

I've read online to use the viewbox etc. and this should then work but it isn't. Am I missing something?

What I'm essentially trying to do is re-create the below. It's a blue textured background, with an interior home image and then those 3 shapes cut out of it (just in case there's a better way to accomplish this?).

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D I posted the code in my original post, thanks.

Comment: That's not enough for a [mcve]

Comment: If you need percentages as units you can also use CSS clip-path polygon() function. There are also a lot of css path generators

Comment: @herrstrietzel Unfortunately I can't use CSS clip-path function because I need 3 different shapes and therefore 3 different clip paths in one which isn't possible.